# Is it possible to count the number of times a specific time has passed between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query that will show me the number of times midnight has passed within the span of two different time stamps. I've tried using `datediff`, but that's not exact enough and sometimes I end up counting more instances of midnight passing than should be.

If I have two date time fields, `entDtime` and `endDtime`, is it possible to count the number of times midnight, or `00:00:00.001` has passed?

For example, if I have the following:

```
entDtime
--------
2019-01-01 07:57:12.143

endDtime
--------
2019-01-04 03:12:44.173
```

And I need to count the instances where midnight has passed between these two dates, logically I would expect something in the form:

```
2019-01-02 00:00:00.001 (count: 1)
2019-01-03 00:00:00.001 (count: 2)
2019-01-04 00:00:00.001 (count: 3)
```

Where the value returned would be: `3`

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by `DATEDIFF` not being "exact enough" and "sometimes" not doing what you want, because it sounds like just what you need. In particular, for the date/time values you give `DATEDIFF(DAY, ...)` yields `3`. Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Were you just guessing that `DATEDIFF` returns the count of whole days? It returns the number of date part boundaries crossed

Comment: I can't see why `DATEDIFF` wouldn't work here either. `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2019-04-29T23:59:59.997','2019-04-30T00:00:00.000')` returns `1`, even though only 1/300th of a second has passed, because the value of the day has changed (and that's what you're inspecting). If you want to count of midnights, `DATEDIFF` is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For midnight, you can just use:

```
select datediff(day, entDtime, endDtime)
```

What you describe is exactly how `datediff()` works.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

Midnight happens only once per day so I think you can cast to date and do a datediff.

```
declare @measureDateFrom date = '20190101'

select dateTimeToMeasure,datediff(day,@measureDateFrom,cast(dateTimeToMeasure as date) days
from table
```

edited:
This should return the same result (and updated based on Larnu's comment):

```
declare @measureDateFrom date = '20190101'

select dateTimeToMeasure,datediff(day,@measureDateFrom,dateTimeToMeasure)  days
from table
```

I think this might be an XY Problem and I will guess a usage:

If you are attempting to count the midnights between the prior row then this is it:

```
select dateTimeToMeasure,datediff(day,lag(dateTimeToMeasure,1)over(order by dateTimeToMeasure),dateTimeToMeasure)  days
from table
```

Comment: Why `CAST` the second date? As you said yourself, Midnight only happens once per day. :)

Comment: Also, I know it is one extra step, but it sure helps someone going back into edit this query to understand the logic easier. I do the same thing with parenthesis around an OR and catch flack here for that as well!

Comment: `DATEDIFF` does not accept a string for its first argument, and while it accepts an unquoted `D`, I strongly recommend not using the (often confusing) abbreviations and just writing what you mean in full (`DAY`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree. It is different in all my apps to what is accepted between TSQL, SSRS, SSIS, and C#. I updated it